# C - does exec have to immediately follow fork in a multi-threaded process?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, exec, fork

**Situation:**
I have a multithreaded program written in C.   If one of the threads forks, the child process is replaced by another using exec() and the parent waits for the child to exit.

**Problem:**
After the child process is created by fork() there are a few lines of code that compile the arguments to be used in the following exec() command.

**Hypothesis**
Am I correct in assuming that in the time between the child process being created by fork() and being replaced by exec(), the child process - being a copy of the parent - will have all the threads of the parent and therefore these threads will run - albeit for a very brief period?

If so, is the correct solution to call exec() immediately after fork()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only the thread that calls `fork` will be running in the new process.  However, there are limits to which functions you can call before `exec`.  From [`fork`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html):

> A process shall be created with a
>   single thread. If a multi-threaded
>   process calls `fork()`, the new process
>   shall contain a replica of the calling
>   thread and its entire address space,
>   possibly including the states of
>   mutexes and other resources.
>   Consequently, to avoid errors, the
>   child process may only execute
>   async-signal-safe operations until
>   such time as one of the `exec` functions
>   is called. Fork
>   handlers may be established by means
>   of the [`pthread_atfork()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_atfork.html) function in
>   order to maintain application
>   invariants across `fork()` calls.

I believe this means you should generally be okay, as long as any multi-threaded
 libraries use `pthread_atfork` properly.

EDIT: The [`pthread_atfork`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_atfork.html) page explains further how the library can protect itself:

> The expected usage is that the prepare
>   handler acquires all mutex locks and
>   the other two fork handlers release
>   them.
>
> For example, an application can supply
>   a prepare routine that acquires the
>   necessary mutexes the library
>   maintains and supply child and parent
>   routines that release those mutexes,
>   thus ensuring that the child gets a
>   consistent snapshot of the state of
>   the library (and that no mutexes are
>   left stranded). Alternatively, some
>   libraries might be able to supply just
>   a child routine that reinitializes the
>   mutexes in the library and all
>   associated states to some known value
>   (for example, what it was when the
>   image was originally executed).

Comment: Is the quoted passage suggesting that the standard library (for example, stdio, `atexit`, `malloc`, thread creation and destruction, etc.) might internally use synchronization resources that could be in an inconsistent state after `fork`? If so, how would use of `pthread_atfork` solve the problem?

Comment: @R, yes, possibly.  It depends on the library.  In some cases, they can lock all mutexes pre-fork, then release them immediately after the fork.  In others, it's okay to just reinitialize them as if the process were starting from scratch.  I've added a relevant passage from `pthread_atfork `.

Answer (score 3):

As @Matthew wrote in his answer, the other threads from the parent process will not exist in the child process (if you are using PThreads).

Note that if this were not so, it wouldn't help to place the exec() call "immediately after" the call to fork, since there would still be the possibility that the other threads would run before the call to exec(). You could, however, control this by locking a mutex before calling fork() - it would essentially get destroyed by the call to exec().

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct about mutexes "essentially getting destroyed."  As I said above, there is a risk of the locks getting into an inconsistent state.  That's why `pthread_atfork` exists.

Answer (score 0):

I too thought , all the threads will be replicated in the child process too. But thats not true. Since other threads are not replicated in the child process, if you are using mutexes/locks before exec, you need to make sure that fork handlers are written to handle them properly.
Here is an article on it.
http://learnwithtechies.com/tech/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=15:fork-in-multithreaded-environment&catid=10:unix