# Why can Glib fork/exec processes with threads?

Tags: process, pthreads, fork, glib

Following is terrible for pthread users include me:

- "Why threads can't fork | Hacker News" https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8449164

However Glib documents say that it can fork/exec under enabling pthread:

- "Threads: GLib Reference Manual" https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html
- "Spawning Processes: GLib Reference Manual" https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html

Why/how can Glib do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can fork() from a pthread, but it may be tricky to do the details right. For example, the forked process memory will contain copies of all the condition variables and mutexes in the original process. Here is a related question, and some guidelines on how to e.g. cleanly release all mutexes held by various threads.

[fork in a multithreaded process with lots of state held in threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223553/c-does-exec-have-to-immediately-follow-fork-in-a-multi-threaded-process?rq=1)

Note that the general idea is to fork(), do some cleanup, and then exec().

For a list of async-signal-safe functions that can be called between fork and exec, see [this manpage (signal-safety(7))](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

But my general advice is to make your threaded application simpler - forking with a lot of state to handle in varioius threads is asking for trouble. For example, exec() by design preserves open file descriptors, so if any thread had an open file descriptor, the exec():ed process may unnecessarily carry around that descriptor. Resource leaks are a code smell and generally a sign of sloppy design. Use RAII if you can.